# Proof of identical eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have read an article "A measure of individual role in collective dynamics" by Klemm *et. al*

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3289910/

"With $M=\beta A^T - I$ and $I$ being the identity matrix. Matrix $M$ has largest eigenvalue $\mu_{max}=0$ when the spreading probability $\beta$ is inverse of the largest eigenvalue og $A$, that is $\beta=\beta_c=\frac{1}{\alpha_{max}}$. We take again $c$ as a left eigenvector of $M$ at $\mu_{max}=0$ or, equivalenty, a right eigenvector for maximum eigenvalue $\alpha_{max}$ of $A$..."

Can it be true that the statement is equivalent, and can it be proven?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you want the proof that the largest eigenvalue of $M$ is $0$.

First, let $\lambda_i$ be the eigenvalues of $A$, with $\lambda_1=\max_i\lambda_i$.
Then, for all $i$:
$$
Av_i = \lambda_iv_i
$$
Clearly, scaling by $\beta=\lambda_1^{-1}$ gives:
$$
\frac{A}{\lambda_1}v_i = \frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}v_i
$$
Further, for any $A$, notice that:
$$
(A+cI)v_i = Av_i+cv_i=\lambda_iv_i+cv_i=(\lambda_i+c)v_i
$$
so that the eigenvalues of $A+cI$ are $\lambda_i+c$. Thus, here, $c=-1$:
$$
Mv_i=
\left(\frac{A}{\lambda_1}-I\right)v_i = \left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}-1\right)v_i
$$
In other words, the eigenvalues of $M$ are $\mu_i={\lambda_i}/{\lambda_1}-1$.

Clearly, for $i=1$, we have that $\mu_1=0$.
We also know that $\mu_1$ is the largest eigenvalue of $M$ because $\lambda_1$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A$, so every other $\lambda_j/\lambda_1\leq1$.

Thus, $\mu_{\text{max}}=\mu_1=0$.